# bash filename start matching

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, filenames

I've got a simple enough question, but no guidance *yet* through the forums or bash. The question is as follows:

I want to add a prefix string to each filename in a directory that matches *.h or *.cpp. HOWEVER, if the prefix has already been applied to the filename, do NOT apply it again.

Why the following doesn't work is something that has yet to be figured out:

```
for i in *.{h,cpp}
do
if [[ $i!="$pattern*" ]]
then mv $i $pattern$i
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
for i in *.{h,cpp}
do
if ! ( echo $i | grep -q "^$pattern" ) 
# if the file does not begin with $pattern rename it.
then mv $i $pattern$i
fi
done
```

Comment: Yes, this will do it - although it has the side effect of displaying grep's output on the (shell, stdin) - will need to turn that off

Comment: @Display; grep -q will do that for you. Although, this is a fairly resource consuming solution. Thankfully echo is a built-in, so it'll shave some of the time off of it. Examining the strings directly would be preferable though.

Comment: True. I would prefer not to use echo either.

Comment: @Display: yes `-q` option of `grep` will do it. Alternatively you can redirect the existing grep's output to /dev/null as: `if ! ( echo $i | grep "^$pattern" >/dev/null 2>&1)`

Comment: grep in particular provides an analogy of reading the actual file rather than the filename string, resulting in wasted maintenance time in 5 years' time

Answer (score 2):

Others have shown replacements comparisons that work; I'll take a stab at why the original version didn't.  There are two problems with the original prefix test: you need spaces between the comparison operator (`!=`) and its operands, and the asterisk was in quotes (meaning it gets matched literally, rather than as a wildcard).  Fix these, and (at least in my tests) it works as expected:

```
if [[ $i != "$pattern"* ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
pattern=testpattern_
for i in *.h *.cpp; do
  case "$i" in
     $pattern*)
        continue;;
      *)
        mv "$i" "$pattern$i";;
  esac
done
```

This script will run in any Posix shell, not just bash. (I wasn't sure if your question was "why isn't this working" or "how do I make this work" so I guessed it was the second.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.{h,cpp}; do
  [ ${i#prefix} = $i ] && mv $i prefix$i
done
```

Not exactly conforming to your script, but it should work. The check returns true if there is no prefix (i.e. if $i, with the prefix "prefix" removed, equals $i).

Comment: The ${i#prefix} should be ${i#$prefix}.

But otheriwse this works. Thanks.

Comment: @Display; no, it should perhaps be $pattern, I was referring to the literal prefix though.

Comment: $pattern in both places that 'prefix' is used above, yes.

Comment: Although this works, should the single '=' not be a double '==', or does the check in the guarded block '[...]' return true only if the left-hand side matches the right-hand side.

Comment: '[ .. ]' is actually not a block, '[' is a command also known as test, with the added requirement that the last parameter is a ']' (hence, there must be a space between the '$i' and the ']'). And no, it should be a single `=`, although I don't think it's really picky about it.

Comment: @Display; for clarity, this line is completely equivalent: `test ${i#prefix} = $i && mv $i prefix$i`